# background-image not working properly in css

Tags: css, wordpress, html, radio-button

I have uploaded the image to the server. Image address is http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/radio.png

And I have used this CSS :

```
 input[type=radio]:not(old) + label:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 23px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 background   : url('radio.png') no-repeat 0 0;
```

}

but the image is not showing on a WordPress page. It's working in my simple HTML page but it's not working on a wordpress ?? Any idea ?

It is used in radio buttons Js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sjx84jf8/

its working here but not on wordpress

Comment: Can your share your url where build wordpress project?

Comment: @MukeshRam its not uploaded on server. I am working on my localhost

Comment: @MukeshRam please check this link https://s31.postimg.org/ui9ho34qj/zzzzzzzzz.png

Comment: I think it may `z-index` issue. Please try to add  `z-index:1` or more in .input[type=radio]:not(old) + label:after class... may be it's work..

Comment: @MukeshRam I have upated the full css, please check

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to actually see what's going on, perhaps don't use absolute URL's (this will become a problem when it goes live). If you are using an FTP client such as *FileZilla*, maybe copy the file path directly from the server onto your clipboard to use in your CSS (but again without using absolute URL's). Is the rest of your WordPress website working?

Comment: I have used this address for image bt same issue https://s32.postimg.org/nz4jpdwat/radio.png

Comment: Have you tried using: _/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/radio.png_ or _wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/radio.png_? Also perhaps try using _center_ instead of _0_ in your css shorthand eg 
`background: transparent url(...) no-repeat center center / cover`

Comment: yeah, i have tried all possible solutions for URL's but still no luck. Is there any other way to show radio button in wordpress ?

Comment: You could try something like _[Shortcodes Ultimate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/)_ or perhaps try following [something someone else has done](http://codepen.io/soulrider911/pen/jHBvq)